# Devexpress MVC GridView ComboBox Column Type DataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, devexpress

How to alternate DataSource in ComboBox Column inside Devexpress GridView by selecting value in other ComboBox column in same row.

It is something like cascading comboboxes but in Grid view (but in grid comboboxses don't have CallbackRouteValues property)

Grid has two comboboxes and if user selects one value in frst the second combobox must change datasource by function that takes id as parameter from first selected combobox

Comment: Found it http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q434150 GridView - How to implement cascading combo boxes in an Inline Editing mode

Answer (score 0):

You  want to use a `LookUpEdit` instead of ComboBox when you are using a datasource, then you can use the `QueryPopUp` event to set a filter to, or change your datasource.

Note that when you change the datasource for the LookUpEdit, the result in the grid might not look what you expected. To remedy that, you want to clear your filter in the `QueryCloseUp` event.